# firebase can't deploy Next.js + konva

Tags: firebase, konva

**Environment info**

Node: v18.18.2

Firebase: ^7.10.0

Next: ^13.1.2

Platform:
MacBook Air M2 (Sonoma 14.2.1)

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "question-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export": "next export"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@iconify/react": "^4.1.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.4",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/pako": "^2.0.0",
    "canvas": "^2.5.0",
    "examComponent": "workspace:*",
    "firebase": "^7.10.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "^13.1.2",
    "pako": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

**Test case**

firebase deploy --only hosting

**Steps to reproduce**

1. `firebase init hosting`
2. Detected an existing Next.js codebase in the current directory, should we use this? Y
3. In which region would you like to host server-side content, if applicable? asia-east1 (Taiwan)
4. Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? N
5. Firebase initialization complete!
6. firebase deploy (fail)

(Before I joined Konva, deployment was successful.)

**Expected behavior**

hosting will be deployed

**Actual behavior**

hosting is built, but the deploiement fails with the following error :

```js
Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

**firebase-debug.log**

```js
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.869Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.869Z] Command:       /Users/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node /Users/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/firebase deploy
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.870Z] CLI Version:   13.1.0
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.870Z] Platform:      darwin
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.870Z] Node Version:  v18.18.2
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.875Z] Time:          Thu Feb 01 2024 16:55:23 GMT+0800 (Central Standard Time)
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.875Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.906Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.906Z] > authorizing via signed-in user (123davidbill@oneclass.tw)
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.906Z] [iam] checking project question-component-demo for permissions ["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.907Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: []
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.908Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token [none]
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:23.908Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token [omitted]
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:24.017Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token 200
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:24.017Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token [omitted]
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:24.029Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/question-component-demo:testIamPermissions [none]
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:24.029Z] >>> [apiv2][(partial)header] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/question-component-demo:testIamPermissions x-goog-quota-user=projects/question-component-demo
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:24.029Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/question-component-demo:testIamPermissions {"permissions":["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]}
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:24.890Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/question-component-demo:testIamPermissions 200
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:24.891Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/question-component-demo:testIamPermissions {"permissions":["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]}
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:24.893Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/question-component-demo [none]
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:25.364Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/question-component-demo 200
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:25.364Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/question-component-demo {"projectId":"question-component-demo","projectNumber":"784916059687","displayName":"question-component-demo","name":"projects/question-component-demo","resources":{"hostingSite":"question-component-demo"},"state":"ACTIVE","etag":"1_a142c992-5dae-456f-b52f-56492cf9d479"}
[debug] [2024-02-01T08:55:35.755Z] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at findDependency (/Users/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/utils.js:188:23)
    at prepareFrameworks (/Users/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/index.js:123:67)
    at deploy (/Users/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:55:54)
    at Command.actionFn (/Users/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/deploy.js:100:32)
    at /Users/jan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/command.js:228:25
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```